# AngularCLI - serve sub project

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, npm-scripts

I have two `Angular CLI` projects:

- the first project is at `C:/folder/package.json`
- and that which I want to launch is at `C:/folder/sub/package.json`

when I `CD` into `C:/folder/sub` and run `ng serve` Angular does start and serve but the first project at `C:/folder/package.json`.
is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Since we don't know your project structure, we can't really help you. Do you have an `angular.json` file in your sub folder ? The best would be to either share your repo, or the structure of your project.

Comment: thanks will check for `angular.json`

Comment: no there was not any `angular.json`

Comment: it was an `Angular` project which I downloaded and wanted to launch but looks like there are many `.angular-cli.json` files in other sub-folders which need update but no single `angular.json` anywhere

Comment: so thanks @trichetriche that was a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was no `angular.json` and `AngularCLI` just did search all parent directories for any `angular.json` until it did find one